# Shortcut for creating single item list in C#

Tags: c#

In C#, is there an inline shortcut to instantiate a List<T> with only one item?

I'm currently doing:

```
new List<string>( new string[] { "title" } ))
```

Having this code everywhere reduces readability.  I've thought of using a utility method like this:

```
public static List<T> SingleItemList<T>( T value )
{
    return (new List<T>( new T[] { value } ));
}
```

So I could do:

```
SingleItemList("title");
```

Is there a shorter / cleaner way?

Comment: In C# 12 as simple as `List<string> list = ["title"];` (similar [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77462474/2668232)).

Answer (score 318, accepted):

Simply use this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "single value" };
```

You can even omit the () braces:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "single value" };
```

Update: of course this also works for more than one entry:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "value1", "value2", ... };
```

Comment: put a 1 literal in the parentheses of the first option, so that storage for exactly one space is allocated rather than the default 10

Comment: The default ends up being 4, I believe: new List<string> { "Hello" }.Capacity == 4

Comment: Can now be shortened to just `new(){"single value"}`

Comment: @clamchoda this is nice! Wasn't aware of this. But, of course, works not with IEnumerable<T> (which was not asked :) ).

Answer (score 57):

```
var list = new List<string>(1) { "hello" };
```

Very similar to what others have posted, except that it makes sure to only allocate space for the single item initially.

Of course, if you know you'll be adding a bunch of stuff later it may not be a good idea, but still worth mentioning once.

Comment: Capacity set to one. I voted for four answers on this page including both of Jon Skeet's but I consider this one to be the most correct.

Answer (score 42):

Michael's idea of using extension methods leads to something even simpler:

```
public static List<T> InList<T>(this T item)
{
    return new List<T> { item };
}
```

So you could do this:

```
List<string> foo = "Hello".InList();
```

I'm not sure whether I like it or not, mind you...

Comment: I'm also not sure I like it: isn't this a "strange" extension of the string type (for example) ?

Comment: I haven't made it to extension methods in your book yet, Jon :-)
This does seems sort of strange, but I like the utility of it.
Thanks Martin and Jon.

Comment: @Martin: It's a strange extension of *every* type. This is generally discouraged, but it's an interesting general idea.

Comment: It hase some internal domain specific language uses, especially with value types.  Take for example: clock.AlertUser.In(1.Minute) reads much better than clock.AlertUser(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

Answer (score 20):

```
new[] { "item" }.ToList();
```

It's shorter than

```
new List<string> { "item" };
```

and you don't have to specify the type.

Comment: I don´t know if this, in terms of efficiency, is correct. But definitely works

Answer (score 19):

A different answer to my earlier one, based on exposure to the [Google Java Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/):

```
public static class Lists
{
    public static List<T> Of<T>(T item)
    {
        return new List<T> { item };
    }
}
```

Then:

```
List<string> x = Lists.Of("Hello");
```

I advise checking out the GJC - it's got lots of interesting stuff in. (Personally I'd ignore the "alpha" tag - it's only the open source version which is "alpha" and it's based on a very stable and heavily used internal API.)

Answer (score 9):

Use an extension method with method chaining.

```
public static List<T> WithItems(this List<T> list, params T[] items)
{
    list.AddRange(items);
    return list;
}
```

This would let you do this:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>().WithItems("Yes");
```

or

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>().WithItems("Yes", "No", "Maybe So");
```

**Update**

You can now use list initializers:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "This", "That", "The Other" };
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Maybe this is due to newer versions of C# since 2009, but I find `new List<string> {"Yes"}` to be better... ?

Comment: @ErikE According to Microsoft documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062(v=vs.90).aspx) this was supported in Visual Studio 2008.  I can't remember that far back to say definitively if I over-complicated this at the time.  Updating.

Answer (score 8):

Yet another way, found on "C#/.Net Little wonders" (unfortunately, the site doesn't exist anymore):

```
Enumerable.Repeat("value",1).ToList()
```

Comment: Confusing but clever.

Answer (score 6):

For a single item enumerable in java it would be Collections.singleton("string");

In c# this is going to be more efficient than a new List:

```
public class SingleEnumerator<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly T m_Value;

    public SingleEnumerator(T value)
    {
        m_Value = value;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return m_Value;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return m_Value;
    }
}
```

but is there a simpler way using the framework?

Comment: That's actually the best answer in my opinion. It is a very common pattern to have a single item list, to reduce allocation size. If you are already looking for a shortcut you might as well combine the convenient with the good.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a gain in using a `readonly struct` here? Also, making it a `IReadOnlyCollection` or `IReadOnlyList` is cheap and may be useful (Linq do optimizations in such cases).

Answer (score 4):

I've got this little function:

```
public static class CoreUtil
{    
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(params T[] items)
    {
        return items;
    }
}
```

Since it doesn't prescribe a concrete return type this is so generic that I use it all over the place. Your code would look like

```
CoreUtil.ToEnumerable("title").ToList();
```

But of course it also allows

```
CoreUtil.ToEnumerable("title1", "title2", "title3").ToArray();
```

I often use it in when I have to append/prepend one item to the output of a LINQ statement. For instance to add a blank item to a selection list:

```
CoreUtil.ToEnumerable("").Concat(context.TrialTypes.Select(t => t.Name))
```

Saves a few `ToList()` and `Add` statements.

(Late answer, but I stumbled upon this oldie and thought this could be helpful)

Answer (score 4):

Try **var**

```
var s = new List<string> { "a", "bk", "ca", "d" };
```

Answer (score 3):

The declarations make it so easy now to do in *C# 10.0* that I don't think theres a need for any helper. Just add the `new(){}` around any value you want to *cast* to a list.

```
List<string> values = new() { "single value" };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
new List<string>() { "string here" };
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just do

```
var list = new List<string> { "hello" };
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the other answers (and so I can pick it up whenever I need it!), but with naming/style aligned with F# (which has a standard `singleton` function per data structure*):

```
namespace System.Collections.Generic
{
    public static class List
    {
        public static List<T> Singleton<T>(T value) => new List<T>(1) { value };
    }
}
```

* except for `ResizeArray` itself of course, hence this question :)

---

In practice I *actually* name it `Create` to align with other helpers I define such as [`Tuple.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.create(v=vs.110).aspx), `Lazy.Create`[2], [`LazyTask.Create`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33946166/11635) etc:

```
namespace System.Collections.Generic
{
    public static class List
    {
        public static List<T> Create<T>(T value) => new List<T>(1) { value };
    }
}
```

[2]

```
namespace System
{
    public static class Lazy
    {
        public static Lazy<T> Create<T>(Func<T> factory) => new Lazy<T>(factory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My solution as well.  Couple things: (1) your list implementation is not public, so it can't be used outside the declaring assembly, and (2) what is the purpose of stuffing these into the System namespace?

Comment: @StephenRobinson reason for putting the `Lazy` extension in `System` is that `Lazy` itself is in `System` [and hence `Create` would appear in the compleiton lists without a `using`]. There's nothing to be gained from forcing people to `open` a diff namespace? Making the other thing private was not intentional; fixed

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate a little bit more:
As of C# 9.0, we have 'Target-typed new' such that when the target type is known, you can omit the type name.

`@clamchoda` shows how to use target-typed new when [declaring a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74394130/3032543).
If you assign a previously declared variable, you can assign it like this:

```cs
List<string> values;
values = new() { "single value" };
```

And finally, if you are using it in a method that returns a known type, you can return it like this:

```cs
public static List<T> SingleItemList<T>( T value )
{
    return new() { value };
}
```

Source: [new-operator@learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#target-typed-new)

Answer (score 1):

If someone landed on this page and trying to add object instead of string, then this worked for me.

```
new List<myObj> { new myObj{propertName=propstryValue }
, new myObj{propertName=propstryValue }, new myObj{propertName=propstryValue }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an inheritor from the `List<>` class

```
    public class SingletonList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public SingletonList(T element) : base(1)
        {
            this.Add(element);
        }
    }
```

and you can use it instead of the base `List<>` class

```
var singletonList = new SingletonList<string>("Hello World!");
```