# Quick way to create a list of values in C#?

Tags: c#, list

I'm looking for a quick way to create a list of values in C#. In Java I frequently use the snippet below:

```
List<String> l = Arrays.asList("test1","test2","test3");
```

Is there any equivalent in C# apart from the obvious one below?

```
IList<string> l = new List<string>(new string[] {"test1","test2","test3"});
```

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Check out C# 3.0's [Collection Initializers](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3607421).

```
var list = new List<string> { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
```

Answer (score 29):

If you're looking to reduce clutter, consider

```
var lst = new List<string> { "foo", "bar" };
```

This uses two features of C# 3.0: type inference (the `var` keyword) and the collection initializer for lists.

Alternatively, if you can make do with an array, this is even shorter (by a small amount):

```
var arr = new [] { "foo", "bar" };
```

Comment: I wouldn't typically be choosing my data structures based on which one takes less characters to initialize...

Comment: @Harrichael Right, and nor am I. But unless you need a list, there's no reason to use one.

Answer (score 11):

In C# 3, you can do:

```
IList<string> l = new List<string> { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
```

This uses the new collection initializer syntax in C# 3.

In C# 2, I would just use your second option.

Answer (score 9):

```
IList<string> list = new List<string> {"test1", "test2", "test3"}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with

```
var list = new List<string>{ "foo", "bar" };
```

Here are some other common instantiations of other common Data Structures:

Dictionary

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> 
{
    { "texas",   "TX" },
    { "utah",    "UT" },
    { "florida", "FL" }
};
```

Array list

```
var array = new string[] { "foo", "bar" };
```

Queue

```
var queque = new Queue<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Stack

```
var queque = new Stack<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

As you can see for the majority of cases it is merely adding the values in curly braces, or instantiating a new array followed by curly braces and values.

Answer (score 6):

You can just:

```
var list = new List<string> { "red", "green", "blue" };
```

or

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "red", "green", "blue" };
```

Checkout: [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

Answer (score 5):

You can drop the `new string[]` part:

```
List<string> values = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify that line of code slightly in C# by using a [collection initialiser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

```
var lst = new List<string> {"test1","test2","test3"};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create helper generic, static method to create list:

```
internal static class List
{
    public static List<T> Of<T>(params T[] args)
    {
        return new List<T>(args);
    }
}
```

And then usage is very compact:

```
List.Of("test1", "test2", "test3")
```

Comment: It this a recommended approach? 
I'm especially thinking about the potential naming clashes with the existing list, if you were to utilise its built in static classes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a typed list with values, here's the syntax.

Assuming a class of Student like

```
public class Student {
   public int StudentID { get; set; }
   public string StudentName { get; set; }
 }
```

You can make a list like this:

```
IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
                new Student(){ StudentID=1, StudentName="Bill"},
                new Student(){ StudentID=2, StudentName="Steve"},
                new Student(){ StudentID=3, StudentName="Ram"},
                new Student(){ StudentID=1, StudentName="Moin"}
            };
```

Comment: You don't even need the `()`s after `new List<Student>` and `new Student`.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume there is a class named Country , than we can do like this:

```
var countries = new List<Country>
{
    new Country { Id=1, Name="Germany", Code="De" },
    new Country { Id=2, Name="France",  Code="Fr" }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from C# 12 it becomes much simpler using the [Collection Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions), for example:

```
List<string> l = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
```

**Note:** The feature is part of [.NET 8](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0) released in Nov 2023.