# How can I create a list variable in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and could not find anything that worked.

I know that in other languages it is something like

`var list1 = []`
or 
`list1 = []`
but in c# I do not know how to do it

Comment: a list of strings is _List<string> words = new List<string>();_

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723211/quick-way-to-create-a-list-of-values-in-c is **literally** the **first** thing google spits out when searching for the title of your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quick way to create a list of values in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723211/quick-way-to-create-a-list-of-values-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

**Replace "Type" with the type of your List**

```
var list = new List<Type>();
```

If you want a list of

- Integer: Replace Type with `Int`
- String: Replace Type with `string`
- Any other class: Replace Type with the `ClassName`