# Cannot convert type 'HelloWorldNew.Vehicle' to System.Collections.Generic.List<HelloWorldNew.Vehicle>

Tags: c#, android, web-services

i want to return my Vehicle passed object as a List or array. The code that i currently have is as follows. It highlights "(List)passed" and the error states

```
Cannot convert type 'HelloWorldNew.Vehicle' to System.Collections.Generic.List<HelloWorldNew.Vehicle>'
```

> 

```
 [WebMethod]
 public List<Vehicle> GetCustomerList(Vehicle passed)
 {
    List<Vehicle> newL = (List<Vehicle>)passed;
    return newL;
 }
```

It would be great if the above code sample can be amended so that i can return the vehicle object as a list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe make a new List object then do `newL.add (passed)`? You can't just turn a Vehicle Object into a Vehicle List, they're incompatible types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Vehicle> newL = new List<Vehicle> { passed };
```

is what you want

Comment: simple change perfect result :) thanks m8.. it say "You can accept the answer in 6mins" so give me 6 mins aight.. thanks again..

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462793/shortcut-for-creating-single-item-list-in-c-sharp. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

`passed`  is an item to vehicle list `newL`. You cannot cast an item to the whole thing, like casting candy to candy bag.
So here you need to add the item to the list

```
List<Vehicle> newL = new List<Vehicle> { passed };

                         or

List<Vehicle> newL = new List<Vehicle>();
newL.Add(passed);
```